# How read the body content from multi part data using java?

Tags: java, mime, multipart, mime-message

I am new to multi part data. I need to parse and read body content of multi part data. Following below is my multi part data. To be specific my data is embedded inside a soap message, not sure if it's relevant.

Using Java I intend to parse and get only the content in bold from the below multi part data, as that's my actual data.

Please help. Thanks in Advance

--MIMEBoundary_8589d345264cb1f477a630c11ab99948c31ab3bfccba010e
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="application/soap+xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <0.b589d345264cb1f477a630c11ab99948c31ab3bfccba010e@apache.org>

--MIMEBoundary_8589d345264cb1f477a630c11ab99948c31ab3bfccba010e
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <1.a589d345264cb1f477a630c11ab99948c31ab3bfccba010e@apache.org>

**X5O!P%@AP[4\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H***
--MIMEBoundary_8589d345264cb1f477a630c11ab99948c31ab3bfccba010e--

Comment: Do you just have a dump of HTTP response bodies or are you working with a SOAP framework? The framework should be doing this for you.

Comment: what are you receiving? a soap message?

Comment: In this particular example, I am receiving SOAP message, but in general it could be REST/HTTP also. Ultimately i want to read body content of the MIME message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by creating an instance of multipartReport like

```
MultipartReport multipartReport = new MultipartReport(mimeMessageInstance.dataHandler.dataSource);
```

and then get the body part using multipartReport